Why get a Leap Visitor Card?
The Leap Visitor Card is available in only a few places. It is 8€/1d, 16€/3d, and 32€/7d.
A Leap Card has multimodal fare caps at 8€/1d and 32€/7d. You can buy one at almost any convenience store. If you only use buses, the daily cap is even cheaper. And if you don’t hit the cap, it’s cheaper still.
This question says they don’t want a Leap Visitor Card, but doesn’t say why.
The only advantage I can see is that the 3-day Visitor Card is less than the 24€ it would cost to hit the fare cap three days in a row.
Is there any other benefit to getting the visitor card rather than the stored-value card?

I believe you have to pay a 5 euro deposit for the standard card (in addition to the top-up amount), while the visitor card’s price is all inclusive, isn’t it? Not sure hence the comment not answer.

@jcaron Yes, I think that’s the answer. You can get the 5€ deposit refunded, but you have to register the card, and must have an Irish or SEPA bank account to refund it to.

As mentioned in a comment, the prices for the Leap Visitor Card are inclusive; with a normal leap card, the card costs 5 euro, plus the value you add to it.
But I don't think that was the original purpose. The Leap Visitor Card predated fare capping. It was, at the time, the only option for all-you-can-eat travel. Presumably they just haven't rethought it yet.
